# error in converting string to object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have following string which I am getting from ajax response:

```
[{
    id: "Abc",
    name: "ABCDD",
    color: "rgba(203,170,92,0.6)",
    div_class: "hotel_name"
}, {
    id: '136',
    name: 'PBss'
} ]
```

when I pass this statically in variable then it works but if I return this same from ajax request and then use it in variable then it do not works. I have used  following code for this:

Not working code:

```
$http.post(urls)
        .success(function (response) {
            var x = JSON.parse(response);
            $scope.data = x;

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

Working code:

```
$http.post(urls)
        .success(function (response) {
            var x =  [{
                id: "Abc",
                name: "ABCDD",
                color: "rgba(203,170,92,0.6)",
                div_class: "hotel_name"
            }, {
                id: '136',
                name: 'PBss'
            } ];
            $scope.data = x;

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

I am not able to find the cause of problem, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just test your response Object is string or any error when u parse it , you can validate your json . jsonlint.com

Comment: is not response but `response.data`

You need to check the content type of the response, basically, angular converts a json-string in a javascript object for you. So, response.data is a POJO yet.

Comment: Whats the error? What is `console.log(response)` ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the result is already in JSON format.try without parsing to JSON

```
var x = response;
```

Comment: try placing `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.data = x;`

Answer (score 0):

The `response` in your code is an `Object`. You can't use `JSON.parse` on an object. `JSON.parse` needs a `valid JSON string` as an input.

Angular will give you the parsed version of the response. So all you need is

`$scope.data = response.data;`

in your `.success` callback. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var x=[];
  x=response;
 $scope.data=x;
```

and also change js code to this

```
   $http.post(urls)
    .success(function (data1, status, headers, config) {
       var x=[]; 
        x = data1;
        $scope.data = x;

    }).error(function (data1, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it does not work? 
A. are you getting error or it is not in the format that you want?

on that snippet you try `JSON.parse()` , we use parse when we send **json string** from the server, are you sending **json string** ?
In other words ,do you use , on your php file json_encode() at the end:

```
echo json_encode($result); //that converts object to json string ,and we get it from the client
```

and then on the `success` we parse the object:

```
$http.post(urls)
        .success(function (response) {
            var x = JSON.parse(response);
            $scope.data = x;

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

### update

the correct json string that returns from server should be like this:

```
["{\"id\": \"plazabeach\",\"name\": \"DDD\",\"color\": \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6 )\",\"div_class\": \"hotel_name\"}, {\"id\": \"136\",\"name\": \"PBss\"}"]
```

*you could check it on chrome console : JSON.parse(all the string here);*

Comment: yes I have used json_encode($result), but it is not showing any error in console. and the api which needs the data in this format stops working

Comment: open your 'chrome'  on the 'Network' tab , you should see the request to your php file:   click on it and on the right side of the window you will see the  tabs 'Preview' and 'Response' , check there what you return from the server.

Comment: "[{id: \"plazabeach\", name: \"PlazaHotel BeachFront Resort\", color: \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6)\", div_class:\"hotel_name\"} ,{id: '136', name: 'PBss'}]"  this is the response coming in chrome.

Comment: i see , you have an error on your string , it should have double quotes on the properties too, it should be like :
 
"[{\"id\": \"plazabeach\", \"name\": \"PlazaHotel BeachFront Resort\", \"color\": \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6)\", \"div_class\":\"hotel_name\"} ,{\"id\": '136', \"name\": 'PBss'}]"

Check again how you convert your array and before you convert it .

Comment: now respose from server is : "[{\"id\": \"plazabeach\",\"name\": \"DDD\",\"color\": \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6
)\",\"div_class\": \"hotel_name\"}, {\"id\": \"136\",\"name\": \"PBss\",}]" but still not working.

Comment: I see, delete you last    ','  and add double quotes just before  your first  {  and after your last } ,  it should be like this: 

["{\"id\": \"plazabeach\",\"name\": \"DDD\",\"color\": \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6 )\",\"div_class\": \"hotel_name\"}, {\"id\": \"136\",\"name\": \"PBss\"}"]

on your chrome console, write JSON.parse(["{\"id\": \"plazabeach\",\"name\": \"DDD\",\"color\": \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6 )\",\"div_class\": \"hotel_name\"}, {\"id\": \"136\",\"name\": \"PBss\"}"])  to check it.

Comment: I am stunned that how not even a single solution is not working.

Comment: I have tried with response: "{id: \"plazabeach\",name: \"PlazaHotel BeachFront Resort\",color: \"rgba(203,170,92,0.6)\",div_class: \"hotel_name\"}, {id: \"136\",name: \"PB Deluxe Efficiency Suite 101\",housekeeping: \"\",housekeeping_status_label: \"images\/dirty11.png\"}" and added [] using: $scope.data='['+x+']';
but then also not working.

Comment: No that is wrong! ,  you cannot create array by adding that: $scope.data='['+x+']';    
You should already return array from server, please take a look on how json_encode works on the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php , and if you could , edit your question and show your php file.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then the problem is with your JSON data.

```
[{
    id: "Abc",
    name: "ABCDD",
    color: "rgba(203,170,92,0.6)",
    div_class: "hotel_name"
}, {
    id: '136',//<-- This single quote characters is illegal. JSON specification states that only double quotes are allowed.
    name: 'PBss'//<-- This single quote characters is illegal. JSON specification states that only double quotes are allowed.
} ]
```

Can you try

```
var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((response)));
```

I think that should resolve it!